# The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition... Flutter Problem

Tags: flutter, dart

In order to edit and update a product item in a shop app, I've created a _saveform() method which contains 2 other methods (updateProduct(), addproduct())  accessing them by a provider as shown in the code bellow:

```
  void _saveForm(){

     final  isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
     if (!isValid) {
             return;
     }
    _form.currentState!.save();
           if (_editedProduct != null) {
                 Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
                                  .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
           }else{
       
     
         Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
                                  .addProduct(_editedProduct);
     }
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

I'm having a problem in the condition if(_editedProduct != null)... knowing that _editedProduct is an object of the Product class.
the code of the EditScreenClass :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/products.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  
  static const routeName = '/edit-product';
  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {

  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Product _editedProduct = Product(
              id: '',
               title: '', 
               description: '', 
               price: 0,
               imageUrl: '',
  );

  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };

  var _isInit = true;

  @override
   void initState(){
     _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
     super.initState();
   }

    @override
    void didChangeDependencies(){
       if (_isInit) {
          final productId =  ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
          if (productId != null) {
              final  _editedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId.toString());
             _initValues = {
                   'title': _editedProduct.title,
                   'description': _editedProduct.description,
                   'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
                  'imageUrl': '',

         };
         _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
          }
         
       }
       _isInit= false;
       super.didChangeDependencies();
    }



   void _updateImageUrl(){

        if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
             if ((_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') && 
                  !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) ||
                      (!_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpg') && 
                          !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.jpeg') && 
                             !_imageUrlController.text.endsWith('.png'))) {
                                 return;  
                              }
           setState(() {
             
           });
        }
   }
// this method used to be sure that you clear up memory and avoid memory leacks )
  void dispose(){
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _saveForm(){

     final  isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
     if (!isValid) {
             return;
     }
    _form.currentState!.save();
           if (_editedProduct != null) {
                 Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
                                  .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
           }else{
       
     
         Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
                                  .addProduct(_editedProduct);
     }
     Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Edit Product'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                onPressed: _saveForm ,
                ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

            // to add an input 
            child:  Form(
              key: _form,
                child: ListView(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                   initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                  },
                  validator: (value){
                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                               return 'Please provide a value';
                            }
                            return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value){
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                          id: _editedProduct.id,
                           isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite, 
                          title: value!,
                           description: _editedProduct.description,
                            price: _editedProduct.price, 
                            imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl,
                        
                            );
                   },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                    initialValue: _initValues['price'], 
                   decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                   focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                   onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                   },
                   validator: (value){
                           if (value!.isEmpty) {
                             return 'Please enter a price!';
                           }
                           if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                               return 'Please Enter a valid number!';
                           }
                           if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                               return 'Please enter a number greater than zero';
                           }
                           return null;
                   },
                   onSaved: (value){
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                              id: _editedProduct.id,
                           isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite, 
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                           description: _editedProduct.description,
                            price: double.parse(value!), 
                            imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                   },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                   initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                  maxLines: 3,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                validator: (value){
                         if (value!.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please provide a description!';
                         }
                         if (value.length < 10) {
                             return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                         }
                         return null;
                },
                 onSaved: (value){
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                              id: _editedProduct.id,
                           isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite, 
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                           description: value!,
                            price: _editedProduct.price, 
                            imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl
                            );
                   },
                ),
                Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty ?
                                   Text('Enter a URL')
                        : FittedBox(
                          child: Image.network(_imageUrlController.text),
                          ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                         textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                         controller: _imageUrlController,
                         focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                         onFieldSubmitted: (_){
                                  _saveForm();
                         },
                         validator: (value){
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please Enter an image URL';
                              }
                              if (!value.startsWith('http') && !value.startsWith('https')) {
                                     return 'Please Enter a Valid URL';
                              }
                    if (!value.endsWith('.jpg') && !value.endsWith('.jpeg') && !value.endsWith('.png')) {
                                 return 'Please Enter a valid Image';  
                              }
                              return null;
                         },
                      onSaved: (value){
                        _editedProduct = Product(
                             id: _editedProduct.id,
                           isFavorite: _editedProduct.isFavorite, 
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                           description: _editedProduct.description,
                            price: _editedProduct.price, 
                            imageUrl: value!,
                            );
                   },
                         
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            
            ),
          ) ,

    );
  }
}
```

The source code of the Product class is :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


// class that define what the caracters of a product
class Product with ChangeNotifier{

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;


  Product({
    required    this.id,
    required   this.title,
   required  this.description,
    required   this.price,
    required  this.imageUrl,
     this.isFavorite = false,
  });

void toggleFavoriteStatus(){
  isFavorite = !isFavorite;
  notifyListeners();
}


}
```

The source code of the Products class :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'product.dart';


class Products with ChangeNotifier{

  List<Product> _items = [
     Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
    ];
   var _showFavoritesOnly = false;
  
  List<Product> get items{
    //if (_showFavoritesOnly) {
     // return _items.where((prodItem) =>  prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
   // }
    return [..._items];
  }

   List<Product> get favoriteItems{
     return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList();
   }
  //void showFavoritesOnly(){
    //_showFavoritesOnly = true;
   // notifyListeners();
 // }

  //void showAll(){
    //_showFavoritesOnly = false;
   // notifyListeners();
  //}
  Product findById(String id){
    return _items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }
  // we have to tell all listeners of this provider that new data is avaialabe 
  void addProduct(Product product){
      final newProduct = Product(
        id: DateTime.now().toString(), 
        title: product.title,
         description: product.description,
          price: product.price, 
          imageUrl: product.imageUrl);
          _items.add(newProduct);
        //_items.insert(0, newProduct); add an element to the begining of the list
    notifyListeners();
  }


  void updateProduct(String id, Product newProduct){
     final prodIndex = _items.indexWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
     if (prodIndex >= 0) {
         _items[prodIndex] = newProduct;
         notifyListeners(); 
     }else{
       print('...');
     }
  }  
}
```

I would appreciate your help, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because dart's null safety feature `_editedProduct` never going to be null because it is declared as non-nullable `Product`

```
Product _editedProduct = Product(
              id: '',
               title: '', 
               description: '', 
               price: 0,
               imageUrl: '',
  );
```

therefore the expression `_editedProduct != null` is always true. therefore that if condition block will be executed everytime.

if you want to assign null to your `_editedProduct` change declaration as follows.

```
Product? _editedProduct = Product(
                  id: '',
                   title: '', 
                   description: '', 
                   price: 0,
                   imageUrl: '',
      );
```

? symbol after the Product means that the variable may be either product or null. then your if expression either be true or false. but note that if you do not need to assign null to your `_editedProduct` leave the declaration as it is. just remove the if condition.

Comment: it worked for me but When I'm trying to update ..a new product item added to the list of items not the same product item updated. for example a product item (Redshirt, 30.99 $, ...) trying to update it as (blue Shirt , 50.99$ ) 2 products (Red and Blue) will be appreared on the UI ..